# ¿Por qué se genera el error Undefined array key?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

estoy practicando creando un CRUD MVC con php, sin embargo me encuentro con un error al realizar la sentencia UPDATE el error es el siguiente, agradecería mucho su apoyo pues ya he analizado mi código buscando algún error pero no logro encontrarlo, por ello solicito su ayuda por favor.

**Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\SISTEMA\controladores\controlador_asociado.php on line 46**
Al revisar la linea del controlador tenemos:

```
 public function editar(){

    if($_POST){
        $id=$_POST['id']; //aquí es donde se genera el error
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
        Asociado::editar($id,$nombre,$apellidos);
    }
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $asociado=(Asociado::buscar($id));

    include_once("vistas/asociado/editar.php");

    
}
```

Y acá adjunto mi código del modelo.

```
public static function editar($id,$nombre,$apellidos){

        $conexionBD=BD::crearInstancia();
        $sql=$conexionBD->prepare("UPDATE asociado SET Nombre=?,Apellidos=? WHERE ID=?");
        $sql->execute(array($id,$nombre,$apellidos));

    }
```

Curiosamente el código para insertar nuevos registros funciona muy bien, de ahi me base para crear el UPDATE, igualmente lo adjunto este si **funciona**

```
public static function crear($nombre,$apellidos,$nacimiento,$telefono,$correo,$calle,$localidad,$municipio,$estado,$cp,$referencia,$documentos){

        $conexionBD=BD::crearInstancia();

        $sql=$conexionBD->prepare("INSERT INTO asociado(Nombre,Apellidos,Nacimiento,Telefono,Correo,Calle,Localidad,Municipio,Estado,CP,Referencia,Documentos) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $sql->execute(array($nombre,$apellidos,$nacimiento,$telefono,$correo,$calle,$localidad,$municipio,$estado,$cp,$referencia,$documentos));
    }
```

Y acá adjunto la otra parte, aclaro que esta funciona muy bien.

```
public function crear(){

    if($_POST){
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
        $nacimiento=$_POST['fechadenacimiento'];
        $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
        $correo=$_POST['correo'];
        $calle=$_POST['calle'];
        $localidad=$_POST['localidad'];
        $municipio=$_POST['municipio'];
        $estado=$_POST['estado'];
        $cp=$_POST['cp'];
        $referencia=$_POST['referencia'];
        $documentos=$_POST['documentos'];
        
        
        Asociado::crear($id,$nombre,$apellidos,$correo,$nacimiento,$telefono,$correo,$calle,$localidad,$municipio,$estado,$cp,$referencia,$documentos);
        header("Location:./?controlador=asociado&accion=inicio");
```

Comment: Has un var_dump($_POST) para ver que datos recibes con el request, ademas el orden de execute del update debería ser `$nombre, $apellidos, $id`

Comment: ¿Desde dónde estás mandando los datos? Parece no haber un dato asociado a la clave `id` en la supergloblal `$_POST`, haz una depuración de la misma como te sugiere @JonathanOrta y dinos qué muestra. Por otra parte, es extraño que `crear()` no advierta nada, en ese contexto usas una variable `$id` que no está definida y deberías tener al menos un *`Undefined variable`*

Comment: Lograste solucionar este problema? Estoy teniendo exactamente el mismo y no se que hacer.